# Why does PhantomJS on Ubuntu register as a touch device by Google Maps?

Tags: python, selenium, google-maps-api-3, phantomjs

**PhantomJS inconsistency between Ubuntu & Mac, recognized as touch device on Ubuntu by Google Maps**

I recently stumbled upon what looks like an inconsistency in PhantomJS between operating systems.

I am using the Python 2.7 Selenium module (2.42.1) and PhantomJS (1.9.7) to test website applications. While testing a webpage using Google Maps JS API 3 I noticed that Google Maps seems to recognize PhantomJS as a touch device on Ubuntu, but strangely enough not on Mac.

I've put together a simple [Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example](https://notendur.hi.is/~sfg6/google_maps_example/).

What happens is that the zoom control buttons look different on touch devices such as iOS or Android devices, they are bigger and go to the bottom left corner.

Running the following python script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
import os, time

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path=os.path.devnull)
browser.set_window_size(1280, 800)
browser.get("https://notendur.hi.is/~sfg6/google_maps_example/")
time.sleep(5)
browser.save_screenshot('test_google_maps_api_screenshot.png')
```

gives me [this result on mac](https://notendur.hi.is/~sfg6/google_maps_example/screenshots/phantomjs/mac/google_maps_api_3_mac.png) but [this result on ubuntu](https://notendur.hi.is/~sfg6/google_maps_example/screenshots/phantomjs/ubuntu/google_maps_api_3_ubuntu.png).

Can I in any way prevent PhantomJS from being registered as a touch device?

---

**Answer:**

As Jeff Sisson suggested in his answer below the problem was the user agent string.

PhantomJS used the following user agent string on Ubuntu:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.7 Safari/534.34
```

and this one on Mac:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
```

After trying and [checking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference#Linux) few things out I came to the conclusion that the problem was the platform token. After changing `Unknown` to `X11` as seen in below example, Google Maps stopped treating PhantomJS as a mobile device.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import os, time

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34  "
    "(KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.7 Safari/534.34"
)

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap,service_log_path=os.path.devnull)
browser.set_window_size(1280, 800)
browser.get("https://notendur.hi.is/~sfg6/google_maps_example/")
time.sleep(5)
browser.save_screenshot('test_google_maps_api_screenshot_x11.png')
```

Running above python script on Ubuntu gave [this result](https://notendur.hi.is/~sfg6/google_maps_example/screenshots/phantomjs/ubuntu/google_maps_api_3_ubuntu_X11.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried manually setting PhantomJS' user agent?  Anecdotally (using Safari on a mac), your test page loads the mobile UI when I set the user agent to iPhone, so it could be a simple case of incorrect browser sniffing.

Here's an example of how you can set the user agent with `page.settings`: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/useragent.js

This example will also log what the default user agent is — and [mailing list evidence](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phantomjs/7Cs4ZfPptAw/lcPZ-c3RTvcJ) seems to imply that the user agent definitely varies between operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

This is the latest for me using Chrome.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36';
page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 200};
page.open('http://optime.dev.puppetsproutatwork.com/email/weekly/7780', function() {
    page.render('github.png', {format: 'png', quality: '100'});
    phantom.exit();
});
```